# Working with precise/unprecise DomainValues in Abstract Interpretation is OPAL

Tags: scala, static-analysis, opal-framework

In my OPAL-analysis, I create domain values in the following manner:

```
domain.TypedValue(org.opalj.ai.parameterToValueIndex(
    caller.isStatic, caller.descriptor, index), typeApproximation.upperTypeBound)
```

In my typeApproximation objects, I have the information, whether its type is an upper type bound or a precise runtime type. However, I do not know, how to pass this information to the respective DomainValue.

I pass these DomainValues to the `BaseAI.perform` method to perform an abstract interpretation of a java method:

```
BaseAI.perform(classFile, caller, domain)(Some(parameters))
```

The DomainValues are contained in the parameters value.

Is there any possibility to tell the abstract interpretation, that some of my parameters are precise runtime types, while some other parameters are only upper type bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory methods defined by `org.opalj.ai.ReferenceValuesFactory` (which are **always** available) enable you to create values that have the required properties. E.g. using `InitializedObjectValue` a DomainValue will be created where the type is assumed to be precise. Using the factory method: `ReferenceValue` the given type is treated as an upper type bound. Additionally, org.opalj.ai.l1.DefaultReferenceValuesBinding defines the generic factory method:

```
def ObjectValue(
    origin:            ValueOrigin,
    isNull:            Answer,
    isPrecise:         Boolean,
    theUpperTypeBound: ObjectType,
    t:                 Timestamp
): SObjectValue
```

which gives you complete control.

Comment: Thank you.

Since I have some precise types, as well as some upper type bounds, i used the flexible ObjectValue method.

However, I had to define a new domain, which made this method public accessible, since it is declared protected.